# Subset rows based on a specific threshold value

Tags: r, subset

I want to get a subset of the columns observations of my data frame, based on a threshold. I'll explain you the question with a little more details.

I have a data frame with the methylation level of 35 patients afected by lung adenocarcinoma. This is a subset of my data:

```
> df.met[1:5,1:5]
                A2BP1       A2M     A2ML1     A4GALT       AAAS
paciente6  0.36184475 0.4555788 0.6422624 0.08051388 0.15013343
paciente7  0.47566878 0.7329827 0.4938048 0.45487573 0.10827520
paciente8  0.17455497 0.7528387 0.5686839 0.37018038 0.12423923
paciente9  0.04830471 0.5166676 0.8878207 0.08881092 0.11779075
paciente10 0.16757806 0.7896194 0.5408747 0.35315243 0.09234602
```

Now, I need to get another object (with the same number of columns, but smaller number of rows, and diferent in every column) with a subset of the values greater than 0.1 for all the columns of the initial data frame.

My intention is to obtain a object like this one (I don't know if is possible...):

```
            A2BP1       A2M     A2ML1     A4GALT       AAAS
paciente6  0.36184475 0.4555788 0.6422624            0.15013343
paciente7  0.47566878 0.7329827 0.4938048 0.45487573 0.10827520
paciente8  0.17455497 0.7528387 0.5686839 0.37018038 0.12423923
paciente9             0.5166676 0.8878207            0.11779075
paciente10 0.16757806 0.7896194 0.5408747 0.35315243
```

In other words, I want to avoid of my data frame, the values smaller than 0.1.

Thank you so much!

Comment: so you want to keep all the rows where at least 1 column is greater than 0.1? or where all the columns have a value greater than 0.1?

Comment: Your initial description was confusing `with the same number of columns, but smaller number of rows`.  So, I thought you want a subset of rows which satisfy the condition all the elements in a single row will be all greater than 0.1.  Now, with the new case, you are not subsetting, but changing the values <=0.1.  I would recommend to change it to NA

Comment: Thank you very much! Sorry for my bad redaction, I'm an english student and at this moment, I can't express my ideas how I would like to me :-).

Comment: Oh! Sorry @akrun, Your solution works for me, but I didn't know that I only could rate one answer.

Comment: @Dani It's okay.  I was just curious.  I understand that you are new to the site.  Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may need

```
df.met[!rowSums(df.met <= 0.1),,drop=FALSE]
#           A2BP1       A2M     A2ML1    A4GALT      AAAS
#paciente7 0.4756688 0.7329827 0.4938048 0.4548757 0.1082752
#paciente8 0.1745550 0.7528387 0.5686839 0.3701804 0.1242392
```

#### Update

Based on the edit

```
is.na(df.met) <- df.met <= 0.1
df.met
#              A2BP1       A2M     A2ML1    A4GALT      AAAS
#paciente6  0.3618447 0.4555788 0.6422624        NA 0.1501334
#paciente7  0.4756688 0.7329827 0.4938048 0.4548757 0.1082752
#paciente8  0.1745550 0.7528387 0.5686839 0.3701804 0.1242392
#paciente9         NA 0.5166676 0.8878207        NA 0.1177907
#paciente10 0.1675781 0.7896194 0.5408747 0.3531524        NA
```

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
setDT(df.met, keep.rownames=TRUE)[]

for(j in 2:ncol(df.met)){
   set(df.met, i=which(df.met[[j]] <=0.1), j=j, value=NA)
 }

 df.met
 #          rn     A2BP1       A2M     A2ML1    A4GALT      AAAS
 #1:  paciente6 0.3618447 0.4555788 0.6422624        NA 0.1501334
 #2:  paciente7 0.4756688 0.7329827 0.4938048 0.4548757 0.1082752
 #3:  paciente8 0.1745550 0.7528387 0.5686839 0.3701804 0.1242392
 #4:  paciente9        NA 0.5166676 0.8878207        NA 0.1177907
 #5: paciente10 0.1675781 0.7896194 0.5408747 0.3531524        NA
```

#### data

```
df.met <- structure(list(A2BP1 = c(0.36184475, 0.47566878, 0.17455497, 
0.04830471, 0.16757806), A2M = c(0.4555788, 0.7329827, 0.7528387, 
0.5166676, 0.7896194), A2ML1 = c(0.6422624, 0.4938048, 0.5686839, 
0.8878207, 0.5408747), A4GALT = c(0.08051388, 0.45487573, 0.37018038, 
0.08881092, 0.35315243), AAAS = c(0.15013343, 0.1082752, 0.12423923, 
0.11779075, 0.09234602)), .Names = c("A2BP1", "A2M", "A2ML1", 
"A4GALT", "AAAS"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("paciente6", 
"paciente7", "paciente8", "paciente9", "paciente10"))
```

Answer (score 3):

To match your desired output (values <= 0.1 replaced by empty fields) you could do:

```
library(dplyr)
df.met %>% 
  add_rownames("pacientes") %>%
  mutate_each(funs(replace(., . <= 0.1, "")))
```

Which gives:

```
# Source: local data frame [5 x 6]
#
#    pacientes      A2BP1       A2M     A2ML1     A4GALT       AAAS
# 1  paciente6 0.36184475 0.4555788 0.6422624            0.15013343
# 2  paciente7 0.47566878 0.7329827 0.4938048 0.45487573  0.1082752
# 3  paciente8 0.17455497 0.7528387 0.5686839 0.37018038 0.12423923
# 4  paciente9            0.5166676 0.8878207            0.11779075
# 5 paciente10 0.16757806 0.7896194 0.5408747 0.35315243
```

**Note:** This will convert all columns to character. You should instead do:

```
df.met %>% 
  add_rownames("pacientes") %>%
  mutate_each(funs(replace(., . <= 0.1, NA)))
```

This will preserve your initial data structure (all columns are numeric)